# Does Gnosis Safe require a positive ETH balance to use?

Tags: gnosis-safe

[image] - List item

Good Morning

Recently I used my SAFE wallet
to deploy NFT contracts.

Its important to keep in mind — I never held a balance in this wallet.

My Safe Wallet holds my proxy contract.

My mother wallet (the wallet attached my safe is assigned to) holds eth and signs and execute actions on my safe wallet.

Again — my Safe Wallet held 0 Eth for weeks/months. Despite this balance my Safe wallet operated without issue or complication.

When executing a update change to my proxy contract — my safe wallet will call for my mother wallet.

Last week out the blue, this changed.

Now it apoears to read for a balance.

While zero - I receive insufficient balance error before any calls to mother wallet. Adding nominal amounts of eth to the safe wallet absolved the error and the wallet works as it originally done so in the past few weeks/months.

I then removed the eth and the insufficient balance error returned.

Second time I added a micro amount of eth and behold, again it worked.

Yet no gas was taken from my safe wallet. But it calls the mother wallet and eth/gas was used there.

My question:

Did the contract upgrade with a change to require some sort of balance in safe wallet before it can interact with a smart contract or mother wallet?

This has never happened up until last week.

Brief:
When trying to duplicate what I've done past few weeks/months without issue; I received an error doing an upload. That error was that my safe wallet had an insufficient balance. After adding eth (nominal amounts). The transaction called for the mother wallet to sign and execute.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't require ETH in the Safe proxy to use because the transactions are executed (and thus gas paid) by an EOA

Comment: Respectfully I think you’re incorrect. Something infact changed. After I explained what I explained, how can you come to such conclusion?

Comment: I added a photo above to further illustrate my issue.
I'm aware that it's not suppose to require ETH.. but suddenly it does .. and its all transactions using SAFE wallet.

Comment: The screenshot you attached doesn't seem like a Safe wallet app. You should raise this with the app developer

Comment: Some app developers are not well educated on smart contract wallets and may enforce the same rules as to EOA wallets (and eoa wallets cant be used without funds for gas).